# How to update array element value through the global variable?

Tags: c, arrays, variables, global

How I can update the "state" element value of "cmd" array by changing the global variable "state" value? The provided example is written in C language

```
int state = 0x1;
int cmd[] = {0x103,0x20,state,0x0,0x0,0x14F};

for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
  for(int k=0; k<6; k++) {
    Serial.println(cmd[k], HEX);
    delay(1000);
  }
  state += 0x1;
}
```

Comment: What language is this?  Up until I saw `Serial.println()`, it could have been C, but it probably isn't.  There isn't a way to change `cmd` by changing `state` in most C-based languages.  If you have the option of using pointers, then making `int *cmd[] = { …, &state, … };` would allow you to make the change, but complicates the use of `cmd` and you have to rewrite the initialization completely.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it's C language. Is there any other solutions to this problem? I have multiple commands that needs to be sent through UART every 1 second but with various different values updated.

Comment: Change `state` to `int *state = &cmd[2];` and write to `*state`.  You'd have to reverse the order of the declarations.  Or you could use a different variable name instead of `state`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler it looks like Arduino code, which is a weird mix of C++ and extensions looking like language constructs to newbies.